# Not able to convert System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1 to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset, typecasting-operator

I have created an interface and a class which implements that interface and I am trying to assign the interface reference the class object after querying it form the database

```
 public interface IErrorCodeMapping : IEntity
 {
     int Id { get; set; }     
     string Errcode { get; set; }
     bool FIBusiness { get; set; }
     bool equity { get; set; }
 }

public class ErrCodeMapping : IErrorCodeMapping
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Errcode { get; set; }
    public bool FIBusiness { get; set; }
    public bool Equity { get; set; }
}

    IQueryable<IErrorCodeMapping> positions = (DbSet<IErrorCodeMapping>)domainRepository.Query<ErrCodeMapping>();
```

But I am getting the following error

```
   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Ex.Domain.Entities.ErrCodeMapping]' to type 
   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Ex.Domain.Entities.IErrorCodeMapping]'.
```

Could someone please let me know how can I achieve this casting and what was going wrong.
**Note**: I have tried other casting approaches as well, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: You can assign a reference of a class type to a variable of an interface type but that's not what you're doing. You're trying to assign a list of a class type to a variable of a list of an interface type. If you did that, the variable would imply that you could add any object to the list that implemented that interface when the underlying list wouldn't actually allow it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Could you please let me know how to assign the data being returned by the Query<> method to a type(interface like IErrorCodeMapping) which is more generic in order to have loose coupling so that I can assign the data returned by the Query<> method during the run time(in case I create some other class like ErrcodeMapping2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the elements inside on the collection, not the collection itself. You can do that with [`Queryable.Cast<TResult>(IQueryable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.cast). In your case, that might look something like this:

```
IQueryable<IErrorCodeMapping> positions =
    domainRepository.Query<ErrCodeMapping>.Cast<IErrorCodeMapping>();
```